# an order of automorphism group of finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

This is problem of Rotman's Exercise 7.9(i).

> If $G$ is finite abelian group with $|G| >2$, then $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ has even order.

How can I approach to this problem? Could you suggest some hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: By Lagrange's theorem, it suffices to find an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ with even order, or order $2$. Since $G$ is abelian, what do you know about inversion?

Comment: What you mean is that I should show that there is some element $k \in Aut(G)$ such that $|k|=2$. Yes, I know it by lagrange theorem. However, how can I show element of order 2 is?

Comment: Think about the inversion map $g \mapsto g^{-1}$.

Comment: Hmm but I think this map doesn't ensure existence of nonidentity automorphism which has order 2.

Comment: @user12469 Why not? There are three things to verify: It needs to be an automorphism (do you see why abelian is important here?), it needs to not be the identity (do you see why the group order not being $1$ or $2$ is important here?), and it needs to have order $2$.

Comment: In the extreme case that $G$ is an $\mathbb F_2$-vector-space, taking (additive) inverse is identity; in this case you need a special argument.

Comment: @Lubin Good point: There is a concern that *every* element has order $2$ which needs to be dealt with separately.

Comment: @T.Bongers Since $G$ is finite abelian, $f:g \mapsto g^{-1}$ is automorphism since every element have its inverse on G. (But I don't know why abelian condition is important. If G is nonabelian then $f$ is still automorphism since every elements has its own inverse because $G$ is group.) Then, $f$ doesn't have to be identity since $|G| >2$, so $G$ has an element which is not the same as its inverse element. Also clearly, $f(f(x)) =x$ for all $x \in G$. Hence $f \in Aut(G)$. Thanks for your explanation. However, could you explain one more about that why abelian condition is important?

Comment: @user124697 Almost: There is the issue that every element could be its own inverse (i.e. if *every* element has order $2$ - this has to be dealt with separately). If $G$ is a non-abelian group, then inversion is *not* an isomorphism; the condition that $(xy)^{-1} = x^{-1} y^{-1}$ is not satisfied.

Comment: @T.Bongers Okay! I understand it. If G is nonabelian, then $f(ab) = b^{-1}a^{-1} = f(b)f(a) \neq f(a)f(b)$. Thank you!!